# Secondary MOSFET in STUSB4500

Tags: usb-c, st, usb-pd

Could someone explain to me how reverse current protection in the STUSB4500 reference design should work?
The purpose of the secondary MOSFET was already answered in [this question](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/488445/what-this-mosfet-really-needed-on-the-stusb4500), but I took a look into the datasheet, and it is written there, that VBUS_EN_SNK can be either 0 or High-Z..?
[image: reference schematic]

[image: pin description table]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When VBUS_EN_SNK is in its high-impedance state it lets the gates of T1 and T4 settle at the source voltage by virtue of the connection through R10.

This ensures that both T1 and Y2 are non-conducting and so isolate the input and output.

Answer (score 1):

If at any side a voltage is present, the intrinsic diodes conduct and charges both gates through R10. In this state the switch is OFF - it does not conduct.

If you pull the gates down with VBUS_EN_SNK then they start conducting.